# Play2 (java?) - How to Augment a Request in an interceptor without using session or flash

Tags: java, playframework, servlet-filters

In a cross cutting concern - Let's say when logging, I want to pass a request id through a request from a 'logging interceptor' through actions using Play2 action composition.

How do I add something to the request in the Action before passing it to the controller?
I can add to session or flash but I don't want to store any state on the server.

Eg if I want to add an artificial header or something, how would I do that? Or is there a 'flash' that is only for the current request? I just don't want any state in the server but eg headers() are immutable.

I'm using java but shouldn't really matter. I'm just using the flash for now as a workaround but it's not really correct.

Hypothetical example:

```
         @Override
public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context context) throws Throwable {
    String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    log(requestId);

    context.flash().put("requestId", requestId);


    return delegate.call(context).map((x) -> {
        context.flash().remove("requestId");
        return x;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add to the request and not the response?

For the response, you can use

```
context.response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

You can also use the context args (to pass things around between the controllers, views and actions/interceptors).

```
context.args.put("Key","Value");
```